# How to get references in APA style using package apacite?

Tags: natbib, apacite

I provide the detail of tex document with codes that is:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{book}
%\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.4pt}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsfonts}
%\usepackage{mathrsfs}
%\usepackage[centertags]{amsmath}
%\usepackage{biblatex}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}\graphicspath{{Graphics/}}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[square,sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{xcolor}
%\usepackage{setspace}
%\usepackage{booktabs}
%\usepackage{hyperref}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\newcommand\aug{\fboxsep=-\fboxrule\!\!\!\fbox{\strut}\!\!\!}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{Thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lem}[Thm]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{pro}[Thm]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{de}[Thm]{Definition}
\newtheorem{re}[Thm]{Remark}
\newtheorem{ex}[Thm]{Example}
\newtheorem{cor}[Thm]{Corollary}
%\numberwithin{equation}{section}
%\definecolor{uuuuuu}{rgb}{0.26666666666666666,0.26666666666666666,0.26666666666666666}
\begin{document}
    \frontmatter
    %\include{frontmatter/colophon}
    %\include{fronmatter/frontpiece}
    %\include{frontmatter/dedication}
    %\include{frontmatter/preface}
    %\twocolumn
    \tableofcontents
    \mainmatter
    \include{mainmater/Chapter-1}
    \include{mainmatter/Chapter-2}
    \include{mainmatter/Chapter-3}                   
    \include{mainmatter/Chapter-4}
    %\include{mainmatter/Chapter-5}
    \backmatter
    \bibliographystyle{apacite}
    \bibliography{backmatter/MyReferences}
    \include{Graphics}
\end{document}
```

My bib file looks like:

```
@book{chandler2002basics,
  title={The basics},
  author={Chandler, Daniel},
  year={2002},
  publisher={Routledge London, UK}
}

@article{sebeok1960style,
    title={Style in language.},
    author={Sebeok, Thomas A},
    year={1960},
    publisher={John Wiley}
}

@book{brown1995elements,
    title={The elements of language curriculum: A systematic approach to program development.},
    author={Brown, James Dean},
    year={1995},
    publisher={ERIC}
}
```

But whenever I compile, I just get References title instead of reference below it which I have type in bib file. I do not know how to fix this problem. Also if their is any mistake in my tex document.

Comment: Don't load `natbib` as `\usepackage[square,sort&compress]{natbib}` when you are using `apacite`. Remove the  `\usepackage[square,sort&compress]{natbib}`.

Comment: To use `natbib` with `apacite` you need to load `apacite` with the `[natbibapa]` option (and don't load `natbib` separately, as @moewe says).

Comment: @moewe Without \usepackage[square,sort&compress]{natbib} I get the same problem

Comment: There may be other issues with your code, but that is hard to tell without seeing a compilable example document that does not reference files we don't know (we don't know your `\include`d files). As always you need to have `\cite`d at least one of the entries in your `.bib` file and you need to make sure your `.bib` file has the correct name and is in the correct file location. Check the `.log` and `.blg` files for warnings or errors.

Comment: @moewe Sir kindly help me if possible I ma stuck here

Comment: Upload the `.log` and `.blg` files to a text-sharing website like https://pastebin.com/ or https://gist.github.com/. Try to run a simplified version of your document first like https://gist.github.com/moewew/df30e83f7e5bfc29f2fa24dad0b8068e

Comment: Are you actually running `bibtex` on the file? To get the references to appear you need to run `pdflatex`, `bibtex`, `pdflatex`, `pdflatex`.

Comment: @moewe Mini version is also doing the same problem

Comment: @NoorAslam Can you get the sample document in the duplicate question to compile correctly? If not, then there is something else going wrong with what you're doing, but it's very hard to tell from the information you have given us so far. The question can be reopened if there is a different problem.

Comment: Then show us the `.log` and `.blg` files. The mini version I posted should work when compiled with `pdflatex apcex`, `bibtex apcex`, `pdflatex apcex`, `bibtex apcex`.

Comment: @moewe In log I get the error Missing \begin{document}. @

Comment: @moewe When I run bib.tex file to compile the reference I get these Process started: bibtex.exe "MyReferences.bib"

This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 20.6.29)
The top-level auxiliary file: MyReferences.bib.aux
I found no \citation commands---while reading file MyReferences.bib.aux
I found no \bibdata command---while reading file MyReferences.bib.aux
I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file MyReferences.bib.aux
(There were 3 error messages)

Comment: Do *not* run BibTeX on your `.bib` file. You should run both LaTeX and BibTeX on the base name (file name without extension) of your main `.tex` file. That's why I wrote `pdflatex apcex` and `bibtex apcex` for the file called `apcex.tex` in my link above.